# Wordpress error in admin post search in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

We have a wordpress in a subdirectory. Something like this

```
https://example.com/instalation/wp-admin/
```

Overall it works fine, but when we search something in the admin post it redirects to the root domain, not to the subdirectory:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=xzcscs&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&seo_filter&readability_filter&paged=1&action2=-1
```

And it gives us a 404 error becouse in tehe root directory has not a wp installed.

I am not sure that it is a problem with the htaccess because everything works fine on the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "it redirects to the root" - Are you actually seeing a "redirect"? Or is the initial link incorrect?

Comment: When I press search button it takes me to the root directory directly

Comment: Ah OK, this sounds like a WordPress configuration error. Not related to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it could be? In General Settings, the site URL is right, is https://example.com/instalation/

Comment: No, sorry. Maybe [WordPress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask this question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/